# Proper way to execute a long task as to not affect frame rate in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, .net-3.5, coroutine

I have a task of deserialization that happens when the game starts. I need to basically pull some images from the persistent path and create bunch of assets from them. The images can be large (10-50MB) and there can be lots of them, so basically this can freeze my frame on the single task for ever. I tried using `Coroutines` but I might misunderstand how to work them properly.

Since Coroutines are really single threaded, they are not exactly going to let me finish creating these assets while the UI is running. I can't also just create a new thread to do this work, and jump back on the main thread when done with a callback because Unity won't let me access their API (I am creating Texture2D, Button(), parenting objects etc.).

How the hell do I go about this? Do I really need to create a massive `IEnumerable` function and put bunch of `yield return null` every other line of code? That seems a little excessive. Is there a way to call a time consuming method that requires access to the main thread in Unity, and have Unity spread it across as many frames as needed so that it doesn't bog down the UI?

Here's an example of a `Deserialize` method:

```
public IEnumerator Deserialize()
    {
        // (Konrad) Deserialize Images
        var dataPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "Images");
        if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(dataPath, "images.json")))
        {
            try
            {
                var images = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Item>>(File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(dataPath, "images.json")));
                if (images != null)
                {
                    foreach (var i in images)
                    {
                        if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(dataPath, i.Value.Name))) continue;

                        var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(dataPath, i.Value.Name));
                        var texture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
                        if (bytes.Length <= 0) continue;
                        if (!texture.LoadImage(bytes)) continue;

                        i.Value.Texture = texture;
                    }
                }

                Images = images;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.Log("Failed to deserialize Images: " + e.Message);
            }
        }

        // (Konrad) Deserialize Projects.
        if (Projects == null) Projects = new List<Project>();
        if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(dataPath, "projects.json")))
        {
            try
            {
                var projects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Project>>(File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(dataPath, "projects.json")));
                if (projects != null)
                {
                    foreach (var p in projects)
                    {
                        AddProject(p);
                        foreach (var f in p.Folders)
                        {
                            AddFolder(f, true);
                            foreach (var i in f.Items)
                            {
                                var image = Images != null && Images.ContainsKey(i.ParentImageId)
                                    ? Images[i.ParentImageId]
                                    : null;
                                if (image == null) continue;

                                i.ThumbnailTexture = image.Texture;

                                // (Konrad) Call methods that would normally be called by the event system
                                // as content is getting downloaded.
                                AddItemThumbnail(i, true); // creates new button
                                UpdateImageDescription(i, image); // sets button description
                                AddItemContent(i, image); // sets item Material
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.Log("Failed to deserialize Projects: " + e.Message);
            }
        }

        if (Images == null) Images = new Dictionary<string, Item>();

        yield return true;
    }
```

So this would take like 10s to complete. It needs to deserialize images from drive, create button assets, set bunch of parenting relationships etc. I would appreciate any ideas.

Ps. I haven't updated to the experimental .NET 4.6 so I am still on .NET 3.5.

OK, reading your comments below I figured I can give this a try. I put the IO operations into a different thread. They don't need Unity API so I can finish those and store the `byte[]` and load the bytes into the Texture when done. Here's a try:

```
public IEnumerator Deserialize()
    {
        var dataPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "Images");
        var bytes = new Dictionary<Item, byte[]>();
        var done = false;
        new Thread(() => {
            if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(dataPath, "images.json")))
            {
                var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Item>>(File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(dataPath, "images.json"))).Values;
                foreach (var i in items)
                {
                    if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(dataPath, i.Name))) continue;

                    var b = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(dataPath, i.Name));
                    if (b.Length <= 0) continue;

                    bytes.Add(i, b);
                }
            }
            done = true;
        }).Start();

        while (!done)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        var result = new Dictionary<string, Item>();
        foreach (var b in bytes)
        {
            var texture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
            if (!texture.LoadImage(b.Value)) continue;

            b.Key.Texture = texture;
            result.Add(b.Key.Id, b.Key);
        }

        Debug.Log("Finished loading images!");
        Images = result;

        // (Konrad) Deserialize Projects.
        if (Projects == null) Projects = new List<Project>();
        if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(dataPath, "projects.json")))
        {
            var projects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Project>>(File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(dataPath, "projects.json")));
            if (projects != null)
            {
                foreach (var p in projects)
                {
                    AddProject(p);
                    foreach (var f in p.Folders)
                    {
                        AddFolder(f, true);
                        foreach (var i in f.Items)
                        {
                            var image = Images != null && Images.ContainsKey(i.ParentImageId)
                                ? Images[i.ParentImageId]
                                : null;
                            if (image == null) continue;

                            i.ThumbnailTexture = image.Texture;

                            // (Konrad) Call methods that would normally be called by the event system
                            // as content is getting downloaded.
                            AddItemThumbnail(i, true); // creates new button
                            UpdateImageDescription(i, image); // sets button description
                            AddItemContent(i, image); // sets item Material
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (Images == null) Images = new Dictionary<string, Item>();

        yield return true;
    }
```

I have to concede that it helps a little, but it's still not great. Looking at the profiler I am getting pretty big stall right out of the gate:

[image]

That's my Deserialize routine that is causing it:

[image]

Any way to work around this?

Comment: Like you said you can use a thread for this sort of long-term effort however you don't need any special way to move the results over.  You can set a simple flag from your worker thread that `Update()` can monitor now and then.  You can't use a co-routine because they're atomic and if you don't break up your file loading you can easily block your game

Comment: But file loading is not an issue. The actual time spent on `File.ReadAllBytes` is not that substantial. The actual bottlenecks are with calls to Unity API where in `AddProject` i create buttons, assign new parents, set text etc. In these calls I have to use slow methods like `GetComponentsInChildren` `GetComponent` etc. I think these calls are causing a stall.

Comment: No, what's causing the stall is loading the file with `File.ReadAllBytes` and serializing the json. Since you're not using Unity's API, put these two in a Thread, store the result in an array. Wait for it to finish then use `LoadImage` to load each one into Texture2D. Until you do this, it's too early to blame Unity's API.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean.  Creating dynamic content at runtime is not the way to make an efficient game.   _Design it.  Create it.  Bake it_

Comment: @Programmer thanks for the comment. Please see above. I have edited my question to show the new approach with a `Thread` to enclose the Json deserialization and ReadAllBytes. Anything else that I can do to prevent it from stalling?

Comment: Like I said, use a different thread for those operations that aren't atomic.  Your deserialisation code is just going to lead to a huge spike in FPS drop.  Coroutines are never a good idea contrary to popular belief and set a precedent for poor coding practices.   https://www.amazon.com/Engine-Architecture-Second-Jason-Gregory/dp/1466560010/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_14_img_0?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=R2SPD3G2VVSGDNWQ2JBT

Comment: Also, APIs that may be fine for web projects may not be wise for games. Here I refer to `JSON` and _reflection deserialisation_.   The former is very verbose therefore large on disk compared to binary and the latter incredibly slow compared to binary serialisation.   All these things will lead to FPS drops; more time spent in co-routines that could otherwise be doing something else; or generally waiting longer for something to complete

Answer (score 4):

There are two main ways to spread work across multiple frames:

1. multithreading and
2. coroutines

Multithreading has the limitation you pointed out, so a coroutine seems appropriate.

The key thing to remember with coroutines is that they will not allow the next frame to begin until a yield statement is run. The other thing to remember is that if you yield too frequently, there is a cap on how many times you will hit a yield return per second, based on your framerate, so you don't want too yield to early, or it will take too much real time for the work to finish.

What you want is a frequent opportunity for the function to yield, but you don't want the opportunity to always be taken. The best way to do this is to use the [Stopwatch class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) (be sure to use the full name or add a "using" statement at the top of your file) or something similar.

Here is an example modification of your second code snippet.

```
public IEnumerator Deserialize()
{
    var dataPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "Images");
    var bytes = new Dictionary<Item, byte[]>();
    var done = false;
    new Thread(() => {
        if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(dataPath, "images.json")))
        {
            var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Item>>(File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(dataPath, "images.json"))).Values;
            foreach (var i in items)
            {
                if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(dataPath, i.Name))) continue;

                var b = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(dataPath, i.Name));
                if (b.Length <= 0) continue;

                bytes.Add(i, b);
            }
        }
        done = true;
    }).Start();

    while (!done)
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    // MOD: added stopwatch and started
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    int MAX_MILLIS = 5; // tweak this to prevent frame rate reduction
    watch.Start();


    var result = new Dictionary<string, Item>();
    foreach (var b in bytes)
    {
        // MOD: Check if enough time has passed since last yield
        if (watch.ElapsedMilliseconds() > MAX_MILLIS)
        {
            watch.Reset();
            yield return null;
            watch.Start();
        }
        var texture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
        if (!texture.LoadImage(b.Value)) continue;

        b.Key.Texture = texture;
        result.Add(b.Key.Id, b.Key);
    }

    Debug.Log("Finished loading images!");
    Images = result;

    // (Konrad) Deserialize Projects.
    if (Projects == null) Projects = new List<Project>();
    if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(dataPath, "projects.json")))
    {
        var projects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Project>>(File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(dataPath, "projects.json")));
        if (projects != null)
        {
            foreach (var p in projects)
            {
                AddProject(p);
                foreach (var f in p.Folders)
                {
                    AddFolder(f, true);
                    foreach (var i in f.Items)
                    {
                        // MOD: check if enough time has passed since the last yield
                        if (watch.ElapsedMilliseconds() > MAX_MILLIS)
                        {
                            watch.Reset();
                            yield return null;
                            watch.Start();
                        }
                        var image = Images != null && Images.ContainsKey(i.ParentImageId)
                            ? Images[i.ParentImageId]
                            : null;
                        if (image == null) continue;

                        i.ThumbnailTexture = image.Texture;

                        // (Konrad) Call methods that would normally be called by the event system
                        // as content is getting downloaded.
                        AddItemThumbnail(i, true); // creates new button
                        UpdateImageDescription(i, image); // sets button description
                        AddItemContent(i, image); // sets item Material
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (Images == null) Images = new Dictionary<string, Item>();

    yield return true;
}
```

Edit: Further notes for those wanting more general advice...

The two main systems are multithreading and coroutines. Their pros and cons are:

- Coroutine Advantages:

  - Little setup.
  - No data-sharing or locking concerns.
  - Can perform any unity main-thread operation.
- Multithreading Advantages:

  - Doesn't take time away from the main thread, leaving you as much CPU power as possible
  - Can utilize a full CPU core rather than whatever is left over from the main thread.

To sum up, coroutines are best for quick-and-dirty solutions or when modifications to unity objects need to be made. However, if large amounts of processing need to be performed, it's best to offload as much as possible to another thread. Very few devices have fewer than two cores these days (safe to say non that are used to play games?).

In this case, a hybrid solution was possible, offloading some work to separate thread and keeping the unity dependent work on the main thread. This is a powerful solution, and coroutines can make it easy.

*tauting accomplishments* As an example, I made a [voxel engine](https://github.com/semimono/OpenCircuit-depricated/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/Voxel/VoxelTree.cs) which offloaded running of the algorithm onto a separate thread and then created the actual meshes on the main thread, allowing for a 50-70% reduction in how long it took to generate meshes, and perhaps more importantly reducing the impact to the game's end performance. It did this with queues of jobs that were passed back and forth between the threads.